# How does default CSS properties (for certain elements) work on Email clients that does not support such properties?

Tags: html, css, email, mailing

I was reading about the CSS support in email clients [just here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). And, as you know, `margin` is sort of unreliable because of Outlook's lack of support (thank you Outlook).

In case you don't know, by default, `p` includes a `1em` top and bottom margin.
So, the first question that comes out is the next one: How does `p` look by default in Outlook? Does have a margin by default anyway but you just can't change it? What should be the most efficient across Email client solution for this?

Is this the only shaky case that exist so far by the way?

Answer (score 0):

Better use less css in e-mail messages, use only basic html and - if you can - only plain-text.

Now if you really have to use css, get same e-mail client as your most important clients have and just do the testing!
It will differ from e-mail client to client, from version to version!